# In a lottery game with differing weighted probabilities among players, how to calculate the weights if I know previous winners & player distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics

I apologize if this turns out to be a simple question with an overly long premise.

I'm playing a game of chance where players are distributed into 5 categories. Call them `A, B, C, D, E`. I know exactly who is in each category.

The game essentially works like this - each day, every player is given a ticket corresponding to their category. And each day, there are 100 empty buckets on the game board. Every player independently chooses which bucket to place his ticket in. At the end of the day, a ticket is drawn randomly from each bucket, and those drawn are winners for the day.

However, the probability of a player's ticket being drawn is weighted according to category. One category `A` ticket has a much higher chance of being drawn than a category `E` ticket, but that exact weight is unknown.

At the end of each day, I know everything about what happened that day except for these weights - I know exactly who placed tickets in each bucket, the categories of each player, and the winner of each bucket.

I do not have the weights assigned to each category of players, and this is what I am trying to calculate.

In other words, I have multiple days of data that looks like this:

```
Bucket | # of A | # of B | # of C | # of D | # of E | Winner Category
   I   |   2    |   6    |   12   |   36   |   90   |      *B*
  II   |   0    |   1    |   5    |   10   |   25   |      *D*
  ...
```

Given this, how do I calculate the weighted probabilities for the different categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really more of a problem of statistics (rather than probability).

Let $W_A, W_B,\dots,W_E$ be the corresponding weights and $D$ be your observed data.
One approach would be to fix a value for, say, $W_A$ $($for instance, $W_A = 1)$ and let the other weights be unknown.
Then, for each value of $\mathbf w = (1, w_b,w_c,w_d,w_e)$ calculate

$$f(\mathbf w) = \mathbb P \left.\Big(D\,\,\middle|\,(W_A,W_B,W_C,W_D,W_E) = \mathbf w\Big)\right.,$$

and pick some value of $\mathbf w$ that maximizes $f$.
This way, we're taking a **maximum likelihood** approach. Does this make sense to you?

---

For each bucket $\beta$ and class $l \in \{a,b,c,d,e\}$, let $n_{l,\beta}$ denote the number of tickets of class $l$ in bucket $\beta$.
Then, the probability that the winning ticket is from class $j \in \{a,b,c,d,e\}$ is

$$p_{j,\beta}(\mathbf w) = \mathbb P(\text{$j$ = class of winning ticket from bucket $\beta$}\,|\,\mathbf w)
=
\frac{n_{j,\beta}\,w_j}{\sum_{l \in \{a,b,c,d,e\}}\,n_{l,\beta}\,w_l}.$$

If we denote by $k(\beta)$ the observed class of the winning ticket for bucket $\beta$, then independence gives us that

\begin{align}
f(\mathbf w)
&=
\prod_{\text{bucket $\beta$}}\,\left(
\frac{n_{k(\beta),\beta}\,w_{k(\beta)}}
{n_{a,\beta}+n_{b,\beta}\,w_b+n_{c,\beta}\,w_c+n_{d,\beta}\,w_d+n_{e,\beta}\,w_e}
\right)
\\&=
\prod_{\text{bucket $\beta$}}\,{\left(
1+\frac{\sum_{l\neq k(\beta)}\,n_l\,w_l}{n_{k(\beta),\beta}\,w_{k(\beta)}}
\right)}^{-1}
.\end{align}

Write

$$g(\beta; w_a,w_b,\dots,w_e) = {\left(
1+\frac{\sum_{l\neq k(\beta)}\,n_l\,w_l}{n_{k(\beta),\beta}\,w_{k(\beta)}}
\right)}^{-1} = p_{k(\beta),\beta}(\mathbf w),$$

so that $f(\mathbf w) = \prod_{\text{bucket $\beta$}}\,g(\beta;\mathbf w)$.
Then

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial w_j}(\mathbf w)
=
\sum_{\text{bucket $\beta$}}\,\left(
\left(\prod_{\text{bucket $\gamma \neq \beta$}}\,g(\gamma;\mathbf w)\right)
\cdot
\frac{\partial g}{\partial w_j}(\beta;\mathbf w)
\right).
\end{align}

On the other hand, a direct calculation shows that

$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial w_j}(\beta;\mathbf w)
=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
\displaystyle g(\beta;\mathbf w)^2 \cdot \frac{\sum_{l\neq k(\beta)}\,n_{l,\beta}\,w_l}
{n_{k(\beta),\beta}\,{w_{k(\beta)}}^2}&;&j = k(\beta)\\
\\
\displaystyle -g(\beta;\mathbf w)^2 \cdot \frac{n_{j,\beta}}
{n_{k(\beta),\beta}\,w_{k(\beta)}}&;&j\neq k(\beta)
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Thus, we have that

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial w_j}(\mathbf w)
=
f(\mathbf w)\cdot\left[
\sum_{\substack{\text{bucket $\beta$}\\j=k(\beta)}}\left(
g(\beta;\mathbf w) \cdot \frac{\sum_{l\neq j}\,n_{l,\beta}\,w_l}
{n_{j,\beta}\,{w_j}^2}
\right)
-
\sum_{\substack{\text{bucket $\beta$}\\j\neq k(\beta)}}\left(
g(\beta;\mathbf w) \cdot \frac{n_{j,\beta}}
{n_{k(\beta),\beta}\,w_{k(\beta)}}
\right)
\right]
.\end{align}

Letting

$$
h_j(\beta;\mathbf w)
=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
\displaystyle \frac{\sum_{l\neq j}\,n_{l,\beta}\,w_l}
{n_{j,\beta}\,{w_j}^2}&;&j = k(\beta)\\
\\
\displaystyle -\frac{n_{j,\beta}}
{n_{k(\beta),\beta}\,w_{k(\beta)}}&;&j \neq k(\beta)
\end{array}
\right.
$$

simple manipulations show that

$$h_j(\beta, \mathbf w) = \frac{\delta_{j,k(\beta)} - p_{j,\beta}(\mathbf w)}
{w_j\cdot p_{k(\beta),\beta}(\mathbf w)},$$

where $\delta_{ij}$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).
We can hence simplify the derivative with

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial w_j}(\mathbf w)
&=
f(\mathbf w)\cdot\left(
\sum_{\text{bucket $\beta$}}
g(\beta;\mathbf w) \cdot h_j(\beta;\mathbf w)
\right)
\\&=
\frac{f(\mathbf w)}{w_j}\cdot\left(
\sum_{\text{bucket $\beta$}}
\delta_{j,k(\beta)} - p_{j,\beta}(\mathbf w)
\right)
.\end{align}

Assuming all weights are positive, $f>0$.
This implies that

\begin{align}
\nabla f(\mathbf w) = 0
&\iff
\Big(\forall j \in \{b,c,d,e\}\Big)\,\sum_{\text{bucket $\beta$}}
\delta_{j,k(\beta)} - p_{j,\beta}(\mathbf w) = 0
\\&\iff
\Big(\forall j \in \{b,c,d,e\}\Big)\,
\sum_{\text{bucket $\beta$}}
p_{j,\beta}(\mathbf w)
=
\#\{\,\text{buckets $\beta$ with $j=k(\beta)$}\,\}
.\end{align}

Comment: Can you walk me through this? I'm afraid I don't remember my intro stats course and I've watched some videos on calculating MLE, but I still don't know how to proceed.

If I understand you correctly, I could fix w_a=1, then iterate through some different values for w_b through w_e until I find the maximum value of f(w). 

I gather that I can also approach this by finding the derivative of this function and finding where P^_ml = 0. But I'm very unclear on this.

How do I calculate the right hand side of the equation?

Comment: I've edited with further details. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Thank you! This really helped - I don't quite grasp the details of every step, but it was more than enough for me to get working with the numbers.